# In Google Sheets, how can I check a list of entries for missing values and generate a new line with the missing value?

Tags: google-sheets

As per the image example below, I would like to scan a list of entries for a missing data points (e.g.: I expect 3 different month names per name entry in the list, but some names only received offers in 2 or 1 of these months), and for each detected missing entry, automatically generate a new line with the value of row A, the scanned for value of row B filled in, and row C with a blank value.

I've tried generating this via an IF formula, but to no avail.

Is there a way to do this via formula, or would this require a macro?

The example below shows the input on the left with the desired output on the right. Any hints are much appreciated!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XZaO.png)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(LAMBDA(n, SORT(LAMBDA(x, {SPLIT(x, "​"), 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(x, {n&"​"&"1/"&MONTH(LEFT(OFFSET(n,,1), 3)&1), OFFSET(n,,2)}, 2, ))})
 (LAMBDA(a, FLATTEN(UNIQUE(FILTER(a, a<>""))&"​"&
 TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER("1/"&MONTH(LEFT(OFFSET(a,,1), 3)&1), 
 OFFSET(a,,1)<>"")))))(n)), 1, 1, 2, 1))(A2:A), {"@", "mmm", "#"}))
```

[image]